# Scoring algorithm for a Game

Tags: functions, algorithms

I have three variables:

> Good points = You get 1 good point every time you get a question correct. The maximum good points you can obtain is 21.
>
> Bad points = You get 1 bad point every time you get a question incorrect. The maximum bad points you can obtain is infinite. This is because a different version of the same question is given to you if you get the question wrong.
>
> Time elapsed = Simply the time it's taken to answer all the questions.

I would like to formulate something that would treat Good points positively, and the other two variables as negative. Can anyone come up with a fair calculation? If possible, is there a way to make the score receive a multiplier according to how far from the mean game score the time elapsed is?

To give some background, I've been playing around with a python script making an automatically generated maths test.

Hope that all makes sense. All replies are appreciated.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ stand for good points, $B$ stand for bad points, $T$ stand for time elapsed, $M$ stand for mean time taken by others.

Simple: $G-B-(T-M)$.

Multiplier: $\frac{G-B}{e^{T-M}}$

Both of these are very crude, and highly time-dependent.  I'd recommend instead having a time bonus, $TB=c(T-M)$, where you adjust the scaling factor $c$ as desired.  Further, both of these have equal weight to good and bad points, which allows for negative scores.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.